# Pressing ALT + CTRL + S cannot work IntellJ idea

Tags: intellij-idea

When I press the keyboard shortcur "**ALT + CTRL + S**", the problem occurred and the event log bellow printed:

**Prefix Key Pressed. Settings... (), Get stack trace from clipboard (C), Get stack trace from debug console (U)**

Comment: As usual, thw Settings menu in Idea should be evoked, but it didn't.

Comment: Are you able to open `File -> Settings` using mouse?

Answer (score 0):

What Keymap do you use in Settings(Preferences) | Keymap? Check what shortcut is assigned to Main Menu | File | Settings(Preferences)... action? Looks like you have set second Keystroke for this action:

[image]